# Relationships EE 2.7.1

Tags: relationships, 2.7.1

I seem to be getting an error when putting relationships in EE version 2.7.1

Error is:

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'L0.grid_field_id' in 'field list'

The relationships looks like this:

```
{generic-call-to-action}
    {generic-call-to-action:cta-image}
    {generic-call-to-action:cta-main-content}
{/generic-call-to-action}
```

and is sitting in a channel entries tag for the generic channel which is where the generic-call-to-action channel field has been set up.

Is this a new bug in 2.7.1 as this has always worked in previous versions.

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have read this question that I posted I thought I would let you know the issue was the install script we have to set up EE.